# Xamarin forms VS 2017 - exception rendering the control

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

[image: Screenshot of the exception]

I searched about this error in google but I have not found a solution to this problem.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: the viewer not show the design

Comment: There's an exception what's that? The exception message, inner exception?

Comment: what does mean ???

Comment: I am also facing this same issue while rendering custom button for iOS. Any idea u got?? . Kindly help me.

Comment: i am need help too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try closing and re-opening the XAML file. It works for me.
You can look also for other suggestions at Xamarin page:
[Xamarin Troubleshooting](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/#Troubleshooting)